# indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator returns wrong index

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray

i have tried following method to search an object using binary search but the result is coming some garbage value.

```
    NSArray *orderedSet = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@2,@3,@5,nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",orderedSet);

    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[orderedSet indexOfObject:@3 inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3) options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj2 compare:obj1];
    }]);
```

It output the 9223372036854775807, Can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Note that if you do `[obj1 compare:obj2]` instead of `[obj2 compare:obj1]` it works. Maybe a hint to find out why.

Comment: That works but did not get the logic, what technical changes it makes.

Comment: I just found another interesting point: If you do `NSInteger index = [orderedSet indexOfObject:@3 inSortedRange, etc]` with you code, it's equal to `NSNotFound`. That's interesting because the return should be a NSUInteger instead (no negative index). I tested on Simulator iPhone 4S (could be related to 32 vs 64 bits). Now, why does it not find it with your "custom compare", could be related to how it's written. Could be misleading because your said First, array has to be sorted, and your sort and comparator are "reverted/opposed".

Answer (score 0):

change short Range from (0,3) to (0,2)

```
   NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[orderedSet indexOfObject:@3 inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2) options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj2 compare:obj1];
    }]);
```

Comment: But why? (adding more text to post the comment)

Comment: because array has only upto index 2 , there is no 3rd index. like  @[0] = 2, @[1] = 3 and @[2] = 5.

Comment: Its length of the range, starting from 0 and traversing 3 elements.